# Chartjs geo - Example USA map prints all features on top of the map

Tags: javascript, chart.js, topojson

I'm having a hard time to create a properly working example of the chartjs geo package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-chart-geo/v/4.1.2

I'm using Webpack with Laravel mix to import the dependencies:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import { topojson, ChoroplethController, ProjectionScale, ColorScale, GeoFeature } from 'chartjs-chart-geo';

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels, ChoroplethController, ProjectionScale, ColorScale, GeoFeature);
Chart.defaults.set('plugins.datalabels', {
    color: 'white',
    textStrokeWidth: 2,
    textStrokeColor: '#363636',
    // textShadowBlur: 1,
    // textShadowColor: '363636',

    font: {
        family: 'lato, sans-serif',
        size: 16,
        weight: 600
    }

});

window.Chart = Chart;
window.topojson = topojson;
```

Here's the package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "chart.js": "^4.1.0",
        "chartjs-chart-geo": "^4.1.0",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.1.0",
        "datamaps": "^0.5.9"
    }
}
```

Here's the code I try to run:

```
<div  class="p-2 space-y-2 bg-white border-1 border-neutral-200 rounded-md shadow">
    <canvas class="container" id="testtesttest"></canvas>
</div>

<style>
    .container {
        height: 1200px;
        min-width: 310px;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .loading {
        margin-top: 10em;
        text-align: center;
        color: gray;
    }
</style>
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        function test(){
            fetch('https://unpkg.com/us-atlas/states-10m.json').then((r) => r.json()).then((us) => {
                const nation = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation).features[0];
                let states = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features;
                states = states.map((d) => ({feature: d, value: Math.random() * 10}));

                const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("testtesttest").getContext("2d"), {
                    type: 'choropleth',
                    data: {
                        datasets: [{
                            data: states,
                        }]
                    }
                });
            });

        }

        test();

    </script>
@endpush
```

Which results in the following map:
[image: usa_map_with_overlapping_data]

Anyone seen this issue before? I've tried to use multiple versions of chartjs and chartjs geo (tried 4.1.2 and 3.9.0) but I seem to get the same error. I also tried to render a worldmap which has exactly the same issue:
[image: world_map_with_overlapping_data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to Maxi Schvindt, which triggered me to look into the labels. I had turned on the `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` plugin. After turning it off, it started working.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't work before with this library but I tried to resolve your issue (I think).

This is my approach: https://codepen.io/Cuchu/pen/PoBEXNx

**In my opinion, maybe the `labels` field is required in your example**

```
labels: statesFeatures.map((d) => d.properties.name)
or
labels: topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features.map...
```

From the documentation, I found this repo with different examples: https://github.com/sgratzl/chartjs-chart-geo/tree/main/samples.

I use the next example with your json data: https://github.com/sgratzl/chartjs-chart-geo/blob/main/samples/earth.html

Comment: If you share your files in a codepen/jsfiddle with the correct library versions I can test and detect what is happening. But try with the label's definition, it should show the name instead of the feature object. And if you don't want to show the label on the map, check which option you need to apply. Check the plugin `plugins.datalabels`, because by default, labels don't show.

Comment: Found the issue. I turned of the datalabels plugin and now it works...